# Meteor template image redraw

Tags: meteor

I have a collection, that has fields; name, surname and image.

When i use it in #each loop, and when get new data, #each loop redraw images.  "#isolate" not work for it.

Every new records come to page, images are redraw again.

```
<head>
  <title>image</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> records}}
</body>

<template name="records">
    <table>
        {{#each records}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{surname}}</td>
            <td><image src="/{{src}}" /></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
  </table>  
</template>
```

How can i fix it?

Sorry for my english :)

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by separating the template into two. When they are separate, meteor will only update the record that has changed.

```
<template name="records">
    <table>
    {{#each records}}
      {{>record}}
    {{/each}}
    </table>  
</template>

<template name="record">
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{surname}}</td>
      <td><image src="/{{src}}" /></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: First data comes but when i insert new data, it say "Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Can't create second landmark in same branch"

Answer (score 0):

If you totally want to get rid of any reactivity here, be sure to use `{{#isolate}}` correctly:

This will prevent re-render on (i.e.) `records.insert(...);`

```
<template name="records">
    <table>
        {{#isolate}}
        {{#each records}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{surname}}</td>
            <td><image src="/{{src}}" /></td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
        {{#isolate}}
    </table>  
</template>
```

But this won't:

```
<template name="records">
    <table>
        {{#each records}}
        {{#isolate}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{surname}}</td>
            <td><image src="/{{src}}" /></td>
        </tr>
        {{#isolate}}
        {{/each}}
    </table>  
</template>
```